# Dropdown list for data entry will only write the first value in the list no matter what is selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have an ASP.NET page with three elements, each in a panel:
`Model #`, `Manufacturer`, and `Description`.
`Model #` & `Description` are text fields. `Manufacturer` gets its values from the DB and displays them via dropdown list.
A user enters a `Model #`, selects a `Manufacturer`, and enters a `Description`, saves the record via button, and a new model is added to the data.

The problem is that, no matter what `Manufacturer` is selected from the list, the record only gets saved with the first manufacturer that appears (so if I select ZZZManufacturer, it will save the `Model #` and `Description` but with AAAManufacturer – the ddl is sorted alphabetically).

I have spent the last several hours running down and trying solutions here on SO & other places for what seems to be the answer, or at least seems highly related - where the elements have to be right between AutoPostBack, ViewState, and the !IsPostBack check in the code behind.

Perhaps what makes this different is that there is a data access layer component - could something there be affecting this?
I just inherited this project and am still learning it - this is one of the final bugs.

**THE DDL CODE:**

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="form-field-container">
  <asp:Label ID="Label19" runat="server" CssClass="form-label"
  AssociatedControlID="ddlManufacturer">
    Manufacturer
    <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="form-field-required-indicator" Text="*" />
  </asp:Label>
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" 
    runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlManufacturer" InitialValue="-1" 
    Display="Dynamic" Text="Required" ErrorMessage="Manufacturer is Required" 
    CssClass="form-validator">
  </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlManufacturer" runat="server" CssClass="form-data" AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="-- Select --" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>   
  </asp:DropDownList>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" CssClass="form-field-container">
  <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" CssClass="form-label"
    AssociatedControlID="txtDescription">
      Description
  </asp:Label>
  <br />
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" CssClass="form-data" />
</asp:Panel>
```

**THE CODE BEHIND:**

**- Page_Load Component**

*I'm not sure why the last developer had this commented out:*

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Instantiate();
  //if (!IsPostBack) { // initial load
  //} else { //  post back
  //}
}
```

**- Full Page Code for Ref**

```
public partial class ManufacturerModelFormUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl {
  public delegate void FormActionEventHandler(string action);
  public event FormActionEventHandler ActionPerformed;
  public event PageNotificationEventHandler PageNotification;
  private GuiUtility _guiUtil;

  private User _currentUser { 
    get {
      object o = Session["CurrentUser"];
      return (o == null) ? new User() : (User) Session["CurrentUser"];
    }

    set {
      Session["CurrentUser"] = value;
    }
  }

  private ManufacturerModel _manufacturerModel { 
    get {
      object o = ViewState["ManufacturerModel"];
      return (o == null) ? new ManufacturerModel() : (ManufacturerModel)
        ViewState["ManufacturerModel"];
    }

    set {
      ViewState["ManufacturerModel"] = value;
    }
  }

  public void NewManufacturerModel() {}

  public void LoadManufacturerModel(int id) {
     if (id <= 0) {
       return;
     }

     _manufacturerModel = ManufacturerModelAdapter.GetById(id);

     if (_manufacturerModel.ManufacturerModelId > 0) {
       this.Visible = true;
     }
   }

   public bool Save() {
     bool bIsSaved = false;
     if (!ValidateForm()) {
       return false;
     }

     PopulateObjectsFromForm();
     _manufacturerModel = ManufacturerModelAdapter.Save(_manufacturerModel, _currentUser);

     if (_manufacturerModel.ManufacturerModelId != 0) {
       bIsSaved = true;
     } else { 
       //problem occurred
       RaisePageNotificationEvent(new PageNotification(PageNotificationType.Error, "Model Number could not be saved"));
       return false;
     }

     if (bIsSaved) {
       RaiseActionEvent("Save");
       RaisePageNotificationEvent(new PageNotification(PageNotificationType.Generic, String.Format("Model Number Saved: {0}", _manufacturerModel.ModelNumber)));                 
     }

     ClearForm(); 
     return bIsSaved;
   }

   public void Cancel() {
     ClearForm();
     RaiseActionEvent("Cancel");
     RaisePageNotificationEvent(new PageNotification(PageNotificationType.Generic, "Action Cancelled"));
   }

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     Instantiate();
     // if (!IsPostBack) { 
     //   initial load
     // } else { 
     //  post back
     // }
   }

   private void Instantiate() {
     _guiUtil = new GuiUtility();
     PopulateListControls();
     this.txtModelNumber.Focus(); 
   }

   private void PopulateListControls() {
     Dictionary<int, string> manufactuerers = ManufacturerAdapter.GetAllDictionary();
     ddlManufacturer.DataSource = manufactuerers;
     ddlManufacturer.DataTextField = "Value";
     ddlManufacturer.DataValueField = "Key";
     ddlManufacturer.DataBind();
   }

   private bool ValidateForm() {
      IValidator v;
      bool bIsValid = true;
      int vCount;

      Page.Validate(); 
      vCount = Page.Validators.Count;

      for (int i = 0; i < vCount; i++) { 
        v = Page.Validators[i];
        if (!v.IsValid) {
          RaisePageNotificationEvent(new PageNotification(PageNotificationType.Validation, v.ErrorMessage));
          bIsValid = false;
        }
      }

      /* *
      * Additional validation checks
      * */

      return bIsValid;
    }

    private void ClearForm() {
      _manufacturerModel = new ManufacturerModel();
      this.txtModelNumber.Text = "";
      this.txtDescription.Text = "";
      this.ddlManufacturer.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }

    private void PopulateForm(ManufacturerModel m) { 
      _guiUtil.ListControlSelectValueIfExists((ListControl) this.ddlManufacturer, m.Manufacturer.ManufacturerId.ToString());
      this.txtModelNumber.Text = m.ModelNumber;
      this.txtDescription.Text = m.Description;
    }

    private void PopulateObjectsFromForm() {
      ManufacturerModel m = new ManufacturerModel();
      m.ManufacturerModelId = _manufacturerModel.ManufacturerModelId; 
      m.Manufacturer = ManufacturerAdapter.GetById(Convert.ToInt32(this.ddlManufacturer.SelectedValue));
      m.ModelNumber = this.txtModelNumber.Text;
      m.Description = this.txtDescription.Text;

      _manufacturerModel = m;             
    }

    private void RaiseActionEvent(string action) {
      if (ActionPerformed != null) {
        ActionPerformed(action);
      }
    }

    private void RaisePageNotificationEvent(PageNotification pageNotification) {
      if (PageNotification != null) {
        PageNotification(pageNotification);
      }
    }

    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      Save();
    }

    protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      Cancel();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the generated code to see what values are being generated for the problem dropdown list?

Comment: Thanks for the response David - not clear on what you mean by that. Are you referring to the elements in the aspx.cs file, or the populate? The populate for the ddl is at:

private void PopulateListControls() and it appears to be populating the list with the right values.  Nothing breaks on the select either, it's just not writing the selected value to the DB.

Comment: I was just wondering if you had looked at the actual HTML to see what the values for each list item were. Wondering if perhaps each item had the same value even if the text differed, hence it would always appear to be the first item in the list.

Comment: Oh ok, I see.  The values unfortunately aren't getting set by the HTML and that's why I'm wondering about the data access layer.  Still trying to piece this together - was left with zero documentation and passdown.  I feel like the whole link I'm missing here is in the codebehind or the DAL - an item called the ManufacturerModelAdapter.

Comment: Well, HTML that is rendered to the browser (not just the markup) must contain something for it to send back to the server. Depending on the browser you're using you should be able to use some dev tools to see the actual list items on the page. That "GetAllDictionary" method is grabbing data from a database somewhere, perhaps you could find the data behind that source and query it directly...

Comment: Oh, okay I see what you are saying now.  Using IE dev tools I see that all of the manufacturers display.  The GetAllDictionary is used by the ManufacturerModelAdapter and is calling the list elements from the Manufacturers table in the database.  So I see everything I am supposed to see, but for some reason saving with a selected manufacturer only writes the manufacturer at the top of the list.  Looking at the Stored Procedures used by the adapter, the issue does not look to be coming from there.

Comment: But are you certain that each manufacturer list item has a unique "Value" attribute - that they're not all the same?

Comment: Ahhh, no, no I'm not. I see where you're going now - as soon as my sandbox comes back up I will check into that and get back to you.  Thanks for all the back and forth on this.

Comment: I see you mentioned that you looked at !IsPostBack, but I would like to point out that the DropDownList is populated on every postback and so you will loose the selected value. What happens when you move the Instantiation inside if(!Page.IsPostBack) block?

Comment: Glad to helpl @wcd, that's what we're here for!

Comment: Good morning - so I was able to get back into my test box this AM.  Using IE dev tools I do see that each item in the dropdown has a unique value.

Comment: @gbs - I will try to move the instantiation inside the postback and let you know what happens.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Just a quick update - haven't lost sight of this or resolved yet.  My dev environment has been down on this network since yesterday.  I will post the results of gbs' instantiate move suggestion as soon as I can push it to dev.

Comment: @gbs I was finally able to get back into my dev env. this AM. gbs' suggestion was the answer - thanks! Do you want to post as the answer so you get the proper record, or do you just want me to, gbs? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DropDownList is populated on every postback and so you will loose the selected value. Move the Instantiate inside of if(!Page.IsPostBack) block:

```
if (!IsPostBack) { 
    //initial load
   Instantiate();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the assist in this solution!

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide some additional resource for future viewers, here is the updated code that resolved:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            { 
                Instantiate();
            }
        }
```